# CGAL - Surface mesh parameterisation

Tags: c++, cgal

I have been using LSCM parameterizer to unwrap a mesh. I would like to obtain a 2d planar model with accurate measurements such that if you make a paper cutout you could wrap it up back to the original model physically.

It seems that SMP::parameterize() is scaling the resulting OFF down to 1mm by 1mm. How to I get an OFF file with accurate measurements? 
[scaled down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsaBb.png).

Comment: Hi, your post does not seem to contain a question. Try to rephrase your post such that there is a question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGALs Least Squares Conformal Maps algorithm outputs such that the 2D distance between the two constrained vertices is 1mm. This means that unless, the two vertices you chose to be constrained were exactly 1mm apart, the output surface will be scaled.

The CGAL 'As Rigid As Possible' Parameterization, on the other hand, can output a result that maintains the area. Increasing the λ parameter will improve the preservation of area between the input and output at the expense of maintaining the angles, whereas reducing the λ parameter will do the opposite.

Also note that increasing the number of iterations from the default will improve the output - especially if the unwrapped surface self-intersects.

Answer (score 2):

A paramterization is a UV map, associating 2D coordinates to 3D points,  and such coordinates are always between 0,0 and 1,1. That's why you get a 1mm/1mm result. I guess you could compare a 3D edge length with it's 2D version in the map and scale your 2D model by this factor. Maybe perform a mean to be a bit more precise.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to explore doing that. WHen I use the cgal ARAP parameterization method - it yields an OFF with the correct dimensions, but unfortunately a 2d model that overlaps. Do you know why one method would be between 0 and 1.0 and one have the origininal values?

Comment: It is a specific method that is not bound. You should use this one when possible because it tries to keep the area as much as possible, where other pethods will probably compress or extend distances between points and you won't be able to unwrap the result o your mesh. The overlaping is due to the mechanism of the algorithm, nothing prevents it.